# Angular Range in Polar Plot

Tags: plotting

I am trying to make a polar plot using the following code

```
PolarPlot[1, {θ, 0, Pi/3}, PolarAxes -> True, 
 PolarTicks -> {"Degrees", Automatic}, PolarGridLines -> True, 
 PlotRange -> 1.5]
```

[image]

What I would like to do is to set the angle range of the polar axis, from 0 to 60 degrees. I've tried using `PlotRange` but this changes the radial component of the function...

How is it possible to define an anglular range of a polar plot?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Edit**

Original post at the end. This is uglier, but cleaner and more robust:

```
tmax = Pi/3;
rmax = 1.5;
u = PolarPlot[t (*Your function Here*), {t, 0, Pi}, 
   PolarAxes -> {True, True}, PolarTicks -> {"Degrees", Automatic}, 
   PolarGridLines -> True, PlotRange -> rmax, 
   RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y, t, r}, t < tmax], 
   PolarAxesOrigin -> {0, rmax}, PolarAxes -> 0];
Show[Quiet@
 Replace[u,
   {Circle[{0, 0}, x_, {0, 2 Pi}] -> Circle[{0, 0}, x, {0, tmax}], 
    Line[{x_, y_}] /;  tmax < ArcTan[y[[1]], y[[2]]] || 0 > ArcTan[y[[1]], y[[2]]] :> {},
    Line[{Scaled[x1_, y1_], Scaled[x2_, y2_]}] /; 
                                         tmax < ArcTan[y2[[1]] + x2[[1]], y2[[2]] + x2[[2]]] || 
                                         0 > ArcTan[y2[[1]] + x2[[1]], y2[[2]] + x2[[2]]] :> {},
    {{a_ (Sin | Cos)[y_], b_  (Sin | Cos)[y_]}, 
                                   Scaled[{s_, t_}, {c_ (Sin | Cos)[y_], d_ (Sin | Cos)[y_]}]} /; 
                                                   ArcTan[s, t] > tmax || ArcTan[s, t] < 0 -> {},
    Text[Style[TraditionalForm[Times[x_, Degree]], List[]], __] /; x > tmax (180/Pi) :> {}}, 
    Infinity], 
 PlotRange -> {{0, rmax}, {0, rmax Sin[tmax]}}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

**Original post**
I know this is no beauty, but just an idea:

```
rmax = 1.5;
Show[
  PolarPlot[1.3 t (*Your function Here*), {t, 0, Pi}, 
            PolarAxes -> {True, False},  
            PolarTicks -> {"Degrees", Automatic}, PolarGridLines -> True, 
            PlotRange -> rmax, 
            RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y, t, r}, t < Pi/3],
            PolarAxesOrigin -> {0, rmax}],

  Graphics[{White, Disk[{0, 0}, rmax  2, {0 - 1/15, -5/3 Pi + 1/20}]}],

  PolarPlot[rmax, {t, 0, Pi/3}, PolarAxes -> {False, True}, 
            PolarTicks -> {None, Automatic}, PolarGridLines -> False, 
            PlotRange -> rmax, PolarAxesOrigin -> {0, rmax},
            PolarAxes -> 0]
 ,PlotRange -> {{0, rmax}, {0, rmax Sin[Pi/3]}}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The

```
{0 - 1/15, -5/3 Pi + 1/20}
```

needs some elaboration, for sure.

Comment: Why not set `PlotRange -> {{0, rmax}, {0, rmax Sin[Pi/3]}}`, but outside `Graphics`, as an option to `Show`.

Comment: @MichaelE2 Thanks, updated. Is that what you meant?

Comment: Yep.  Looks better, even if a bit of a hack. (+1)

Comment: @MichaelE2 It is much worse than a hack! And I'm not really sure that it will work in most situations, but I'm really clueless about how do it better.

Comment: Yes, I looked at it and punted.  It doesn't seem that `PolarPlot` is set up to handle this sort of situation.  Still your answer lets the OP do what is asked.  Maybe someone will post a better approach.

Comment: Thank you very much for you answer! It is really working. Thank's a lot!

Comment: Oh I didn't see your edit! I made a function exactly the same as yours :)

Comment: @Silvia But your pictures are nicer ;D +1

Answer (score 13):

What is most interesting is, unlike `Plot`, `PolarPlot` uses *explicit graphics primitives* to present axes and grids, so we can "filter" out things which is out of our interested range by force (though which is not a beautiful method).

Here is my brute-force function. I've made it capable of dealing with range crossing  $\theta=0$, but yet added a feature which should rotate the axes into the interested range when it's not.

```
Clear[polarRangeFunc]
polarRangeFunc[graph_, \[Alpha]_, \[Beta]_] := 
 Module[{\[Theta]min, \[Theta]max, sgn, rangeFunc},
  {\[Theta]min, \[Theta]max} = Sort[Mod[{\[Alpha], \[Beta]}, 2 \[Pi]]];
  sgn = Sign[\[Alpha] \[Beta]];
  rangeFunc[pos_] := 
   If[pos == {0, 0}, False, 
    If[sgn == -1, #, Not@#] &[\[Theta]min <= 
      Mod[Arg[{1, I}.pos], 2 \[Pi]] <= \[Theta]max]];
  graph /. (PlotRange -> _) :> AbsoluteOptions[Graphics[{
          Disk[{0, 0}, 
           Max[Abs[
             PlotRange /. 
              AbsoluteOptions[graph, PlotRange]]], {\[Alpha], \[Beta]}]
          }], PlotRange] //
     ReplacePart[#, {1, 5} -> (#[[1, 5]] /.
          {Line[{Scaled[_, pos_], Scaled[_, pos_]}] /; 
             rangeFunc[pos] :> Line[{}],
           annoymousTicks_?(MatchQ[#, 
                Line[{{{_, _}, Scaled[__]} ..}]] &) :>
            (annoymousTicks /. {pos_, Scaled[__]} /; rangeFunc[pos] :>
                Sequence[]),
           Text[_, 
              Offset[_, pos_], ___] /; (rangeFunc@
               If[Head[pos] === Scaled, pos[[2]], pos]) :> Sequence[],
           Circle[orig_, radius_, angleRange_] :> 
            Circle[orig, radius, {\[Alpha], \[Beta]}]}
         )] & //
    ReplacePart[#, {1, 1} -> (#[[1, 1]] /.
         {Line[{{0, 0}, pos_}] /; rangeFunc[pos] :> Line[{}],
          Circle[orig_, radius_, angleRange_] :> 
           Circle[orig, radius, {\[Alpha], \[Beta]}]}
        )] & //
   ReplacePart[#, {1, 3} -> (#[[1, 3]] /.
        Line[pts_] :> 
         Line[pts /. {x_, y_} /; rangeFunc[{x, y}] :> "outpt" //
           (SplitBy[#, StringQ] /. "outpt" -> Sequence[]) &]
       )] &
  ]
```

And here is an example:

```
polorgraph = 
 PolarPlot[{2 \[Theta]^(-1/3), 3 Cos[\[Theta]^(1/2)]},
 {\[Theta], .01, 10 \[Pi]}, 
  PlotStyle -> {Directive[Red, Thick], Directive[Purple, Thick]},
  PolarAxes -> True, PolarAxesOrigin -> {\[Pi]/6, 3}, PlotRange -> 3, 
  PolarTicks -> {"Degrees", Automatic}, PolarGridLines -> True]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
polarRangeFunc[polorgraph, \[Pi]/6, \[Pi]/2]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
polarRangeFunc[polorgraph, -\[Pi]/6, 6 \[Pi]/5]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Aren't the radial tick labels curiously positioned? (Same in my answer)

Comment: @belisarius See my edit please. I modified the `rangeFunc` function to include a special case at `{0,0}`.

Comment: Much better :).

Comment: @belisarius Thanks:) There are still problem about the cutting-off of the function line on the boundaries. I should add an interpolation, but it's already a mess of code, I kind of feel tired to modify it now.+_+|||

Comment: I think that could be fixed with RegionFunction, but anyway agree: this is too much code for a narrow usage universe. Let it be :)