# How to draw a circle axis by AxisObject

Tags: graphics, bugs, ticks

This is my current try, but I don't know why it cannot put in the right position:

```
Graphics[AxisObject[
  Line[Table[{ Cos[t], Sin[t]}, {t, 0, 2 Pi, 0.01}]], 
  TickPositions -> {10}, TickLabels -> {Range[0, 7 Pi/4, Pi/4]}]]
```

[image]

Actually, I think `TickPositions -> {9}` should serve me. Is it a bug or I have missed something?

Comment: help says AxisObject is Experimental. So it could have rough edges to it. I never used it myself.

Comment: @Nasser So any workaround can do this?

Comment: fyi, related [angular-range-in-polar-plot](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/19964/angular-range-in-polar-plot)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
Graphics[AxisObject[Circle[], {0, 2 \[Pi]}, 
  TickPositions -> {{\[Pi]/4}}, 
  TickLabels -> {Range[0, 7 Pi/4, Pi/4]}]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 7):

I find a workaround:

```
ListPolarPlot[{}, PolarAxes -> {True, False}, 
 PolarTicks -> {Range[0, 7 Pi/4, Pi/4], Automatic}, PlotRange -> 1.3]
```

[image]